# How to change background row color of merged datasets?

Tags: c#

I merged() several datasets into one main dataset to something like this:

```
maindataset.Tables[0].merge(other1DataSet.Tables[0])
maindataset.Tables[0].Merge(other2DataSet.Tables[0])
```

I made it display into a datagrid (maindatagrid). Is there a way to specify a color for each row for the dataset?

Currently I can make maindatagrid rows colored like this:

```
foreach(UltraGridRow row in maindatagrid.Rows)
{
row.CellAppearance.BackColor = color.lightblue
}
```

I would like to color each datagrid but specifying the merged data grids are not working in the above code. Anyone know a better way in changing the row colors for each datagrid?

Comment: Are you using Winforms or ASP.Net?

Answer (score 0):

try doing it like this using cell style variable

```
     DataGridViewCellStyle  = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
     blue.ForeColor = Color.Blue;



    foreach(UltraGridRow row in maindatagrid.Rows)
    {
    row.DefaultCellStyle = blue;
    }
```